# Disable "Save space by optimizing storage" pop-up

Tags: macos, notifications, disk-space

I just upgraded to macOS Sierra and the pop-up prevalence is driving me crazy.

I am using a 2011 Macbook Air with only 256GB SSD space, and have consistently had 10GB or less storage remaining since almost immediately after purchasing.

I am getting pop-ups saying "You only have 10.27 GB of storage left, Save space by optimizing storage". They are similar in nature to the pop-ups described in these two questions: [Silencing "Your disk is almost full" notification](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254485/silencing-your-disk-is-almost-full-notification) and [Disable "Optimized Storage" popup?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264988/disable-optimized-storage-popup)

However, neither of these questions have answers to their [slightly] different pop-ups.

**Is there any way to disable these pop-ups entirely?** It is not possible for me to free up more storage on anything longer than an extremely short term basis, so that is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: @dwightk Just wondering, did you read my question? I cite that question in my question.

Comment: Barring some sort of terminal magic, the answer is either no, or reduce the amount of stuff you have on your SSD, but because maybe someone out there possibly knows some flag you could change you won't ever get a definitive "no". Asking the question again isn't how Ask Different is supposed to work. Maybe you could edit the original to include your alternate alert text.

Comment: @dwightk The question already has my alternate alert text in the 3rd text block. I am looking for "some sort of terminal magic". If someone can figure out how to disable the entire notification center using terminal, I'm willing to bet someone can figure out how to disable these notifications using terminal.

Comment: Adding a third question because the two existing ones didn't gather any useful answers doesn't increase the chance to get an answer. The original question asks for a way to silence those popups which includes terminal-level magic.