# How to silence “Your disk is almost full” notification on MacOS Mojave 10.14.1 (18B75)

Tags: macos, notifications, disk-space

I'm getting this message every 2 min and it really drives me crazy!!! I already tried following things that were suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254485/silencing-your-disk-is-almost-full-notification). It still pops-up every 2 min.

Some outputs of my machine:

```
$ defaults read com.apple.diskspaced
{
    checkAllVolumes = 0;
    debugLog = 1;
    freeSpaceWarningLevel = 1;
    lastWarningDate = "2020-05-05";
    minFreeSpace = 1;
    removeAllNotifications = 1;
    warningInterval = 36000000000;
}
```

I set these values by myself and also tried other values but nothing worked.

```
$ grep com.apple.diskspaced /var/log/system.log
```

I set the debug level to 1 (as you can see from the defaults before) so I thought maybe there is something in the logs. Turned out that there is nothing.

I also tried something that is mentioned [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342667/how-to-access-a-launch-daemons-values-system-defaults-value).

```
$ grep -A6 debugLog <(strings $(find /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks -name diskspaced -print -quit))
debugLog (BOOL) - log additional debug information. Default: NO
Commands:
removeAllNotifications - Removes all scheduled and delivered user notificiations.
removeAllNotifications
com.apple.diskspaced
_mbsetupuser
Ignoring low disk notification during migration.
--
debugLog
systemUpdateDate
com.apple.updatesettings
Interval since system update :%f
alloc
init
lowSpaceTimer
```

Maybe this helps somebody to understand this service and helps to solve this bug.

PS: Yes I know that it isn't the best solution to ignore this issue BUT I can't afford a new mac and I can't delete any files because I already did! I only have 128 GB and 80 of them are programs the rest is reserved for MacOS. All files are on a separate SD-Card.

Comment: See this : https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/345120/237687

Comment: I don't think that is a good idea. This completely disables the daemon and since nobody really knows what else this daemon does (maybe some system critical stuff) this could break something on longterm or disable other features which are maybe useful or necessary. But yeah this is also a way to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Put the programs on an external USB drive. They need no special write speed and you’ll be super happy once you get enough space for the OS to breathe.

You’re right 128 GB is too small to let everything sit where it gets installed. I’d say you should have 15 GB free on the root filesystem for the best experience.

If you’re not sure which apps are easily relocated, please post an image of your Applications folder, calculate size, sort descending so we can help point out easy apps to thin or move if you want help there.

Comment: Didn't know it's possible to outsource programs on MacOS. My biggest problem is that I only have really really big programs. For example the whole creative cloud with every program about 1,5GB, Microsoft Office suit (each about 1GB) and a couple of IDEs with each 1GB. How can I put something like Microsoft Word on an SD-Card? Just copie and then softlink it back to /Applications?