# Silencing “Your disk is almost full” notification

Tags: notifications, mojave, disk-space

Since none of the solutions found here [Silencing "Your disk is almost full" notification](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254485/silencing-your-disk-is-almost-full-notification) worked for me on Mojave, I simply disabled the daemon:

```
sudo mv /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StorageManagement.framework/Resources/diskspaced /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StorageManagement.framework/Resources/diskspaced.disabled
```

Brute force, I know, but unloading/removing/disabling using `launchctl` didn't work and I got annoyed.

Is there a more elegant way to turn off Apple's constant nannying alert messages?

Answer (score 0):

Put mac on do not disturb - this worked for me w/ Mojave

Comment: I mean it works...but then none of your notifications come through.

Comment: I just want to turn off the disk notification, not all.