# How do you silence Mojave "Your Disk is almost full" notification?

Tags: mojave, notifications, disk-space

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254485/silencing-your-disk-is-almost-full-notification) is over 2 years old and doesn't work with the newest version of MacOS (10.14.2).

I've tried clearing cache space, and I have almost 5GB free but it still feels the need to notify me every 3 minutes which is both distracting *and* unhelpful.

[This](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7729512) is also not helpful at all.

Comment: 5GB just isn't enough free space! There's a reason macOS is warning you with such fervor.

Comment: The old question is still applicable, it's the current answer that is out of date. Someone needs to post a new answer to the existing question—if a solution actually exists, which it very well may not.

Comment: I agree with you. I would not mess around in terminal for this. nor would I do this -- Optimize Storage

Comment: macOS needs free space to use as temporary space.  You should try to free up some space. delete some apps you are not using. Delete a video or two.

Comment: I'm going to remove the comments that try to answer some aspect of this. Comments are for question clarification. Posting an answer in the answer section of the linked question or editing this so it's super clear how it's not a duplicate would be the best way to get an answer here.

Comment: Please see https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3480/false-duplicate-marking for the discussion about why this is a duplicate, and which edits could help to reopen it.